# How to optimize CGContext memory consumption when drawing many UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I wrote a function to help draw a array of `UIImage` onto a single `UIImage` with the following code block in Swift:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

for index in 0..<numPrintsPerTemplate {

  // .... update x,y positions for the image ...

  let image = images[index]
  let imageRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
  image.draw(in: imageRect, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)

}

let template = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return template
```

It works okay for a small number of UIImage, but keep crashing due to high memory consumption. I attempted to wrap this block of code in `autoreleasepool {}`, but was not successful. Another attempt I tried was to put `autoreleasepool {}` within the `for-loop`, still no luck...

Anybody ran into this issue before? Did I miss anything obvious?

Comment: find solution??

Answer (score 0):

Try putting calls of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` in for loop. It will limit the amount of data processing in a session, i.e. only one image will be processed in one context.